# c# menustrip key value

Tags: c#, winforms, menu, key, menuitem

I was watching a tutorial video on the MenuStrip control for WindowsForms and the video provided by MSDN site indicates you could reference a specific menu item using a "key" rather than an index number - but they never explained how and a quick search yielded me with no results.

How can you reference a menu item by its name rather than an index number (which can change if you add new menu items) ?

Comment: can you post your sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the same way as the index.  Just provide a `string` representing the name of the menu item instead of the known index of the item.  This is known as the `key` value.

index Example:

```
    var fileMenuItem = menuStrip1.Items[0];
```

string Example:

```
    var fileMenuItem = menuStrip1.Items["File"];
```